# Firefox Extensions and XPI installer not working

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, xpi

Hello Im attempting to build a Firefox extension but have run into an issue creating the XPI file,

This tutorial says that the XPI is simply a zip folder renamed, Ive taken a previously installed extension (pinterest) renamed to .zip and it will extract - I can see the plugin files no problem.

If I try and zip then rename my extension to .xpi the plugin will not install - Ive tested this with the pinterest plugin mentioned above and if I rename to zip, extract then rezip and rename back to zpi - the same code will not install. I think there is an issue with the zipping method im using  (Windows 7 > Sendto > Compressed .zip)

Just to be clear - I'm not sure my plugin works properly yet, still getting a grip on the files required and naming conventions - however a working package will not work with the same zip process.

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was zipping from the parent location /folder/contents
Instead of from the contents location

Wokring now.

Comment: Check out https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/xpicompiler/ and https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/github-extension-installer/ it helps in installing xpi from source files (does the zipping and dropping into ff for you).